# When printing a char array why is `*` not used?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 3;

int main () {

   int  var[] = {10, 100, 200};
   int i, *ptr[MAX];

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      ptr[i] = &var[i]; /* assign the address of integer. */
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i] );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

In the above code `*ptr[i]` is used to print the value where as when a  array of pointers to character is used as in the below example only `name[i]` is used and not with `*`

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 4;

int main () {

   char *names[] = {
      "Zara Ali",
      "Hina Ali",
      "Nuha Ali",
      "Sara Ali",
   };

   int i = 0;

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declare and array of pointers with `int *ptr[MAX];` (`MAX` of them), you reference an individual pointer in the array with `ptr[foo]`, just as you declare a character pointer as `char *ptr;` and you reference the address stored at that location with `ptr` -- no tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `informaticienzero` said, when using `printf(...)` with `%d`, `printf(...)` expects you to provide an `int` value. However `printf(...)` with `%s` wants you to provide a `char*` value.

In your case:

`ptr` => `int**`, thus `ptr[i]` => `int*` and `*ptr[i]` => `int`

`names` => `char**`, thus `names[i]` => `char*`.

`printf(...)` then uses `char*` to iterate over characters until it finds `\0` character which is basically "the end". Also, when working with constant size arrays, try to use `sizeof` operator to determine size of an array. This way you won't need to define `MAX`. However, when passing array to a function, it looses its size information and `sizeof` won't work. This means you should pass size as a separate variable along with array.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `names[i]` is of type `char*`, and it's exactly what `printf("%s")` is expecting. Using a `*` front of it would give a single `char`.

On the opposite, `ptr[i]` is of type `int*`. And that's because `printf("%d")` expects a single `int` that a `*` is needed front of `ptr`.